# How to regex match excluding certain characters?

Tags: java, regex

I tried to Google for this but didn't find a solution yet.

Say I start with a string `"aaabbccd"`. I then modify it by adding some special characters like this:

- `"aa[ab]bccd"`
- `"aa[a[b]bc]cd"`
- `"[aa[a[b]bc]cd]"`

As I am modifying the string, I want to regex match on it without the characters `[` and `]`. Example:
For the input string

```java
String s = "aa[ab]bccd"
s.matches(<my_regex_here>) // trying to match "bbc" should return true
s = "aa[a[b]bc]cd";
s.matches(<my_regex_here>) // trying to match for "abb" should return true
```

I tried using negative lookahead but if my understanding is correct, it will only work if I you know the exact position of the characters you want to exclude. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't `b[\[\]]*b[\[\]]*c` work?

Comment: Your comments in the code add more confusion than it helps. Why should it match "bbc" in the first one? Or why "abb" in the second one?

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear. What I was trying to say is I will not know the positions of `[`and `]` ahead of time and they change during runtime. `bbc` should return true if you remove all occurrences of `[` and `]` from the string, similarly for the latter.

Comment: Then I would just go with a simple `s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").contains("abb")` and not mess with regex that much.

Answer (score 2):

Can be like this

```
s.replaceAll("\\[", "")
                .replaceAll("\\]", "")
                .matches(<my_regex_here>)
```